# Ruby on Rails link_to_unless_current not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to use link_to_unless_current to insert some links (as you do).
My display code is:

```
  <div>
   <div><% link_to_unless_current 'Right Eye', {:action => 'graphnew', :params => {:right => true}} %></div>
   <div><% link_to_unless_current 'Left Eye', {:action => 'graphnew', :params => {:left => true}} %></div>
   <div><% link_to_unless_current 'Both Eyes', {:action => 'graphnew'} %></div>
   <div><% link_to_unless_current 'Show Natural History', {:action => 'graphnew', :params => {:nh => true}} %></div>
  </div>
```

The controller is "PatientsController", and the action is "graphnew" and the route is:

```
/patients/:id/graphnew {:controller=>"patients", :action=>"graphnew"}
```

And all it is rendering are blank div's (`<div></div>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `<%`, which doesn't render the ruby code in the view. If we do `<%=`, you should see them.

```
  <div>
   <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Right Eye', {:action => 'graphnew', :params => {:right => true}} %></div>
   <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Left Eye', {:action => 'graphnew', :params => {:left => true}} %></div>
   <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Both Eyes', {:action => 'graphnew'} %></div>
   <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Show Natural History', {:action => 'graphnew', :params => {:nh => true}} %></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a change in your routes file...

```
get '/graphnew', to: 'patients#graphnew'
```

then your path will be...

```
<div>
  <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Right Eye', graphnew_path(right: true) %></div>
  <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Left Eye', graphnew_path(left: true) %></div>
  <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Both Eyes', graphnew_path %></div>
  <div><%= link_to_unless_current 'Show Natural History', graphnew_path(nh: true) %></div>
</div>
```

I think that will work...